# How many boys have passed given the following conditions?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

> A School has $2000$ students,out of which $40$% of the students are in higher secondary.Out of the students in the higher secondary, $28$% are girls and $50$% of them passed.The overall pass percentage in the higher secondary is $40$%. How many boys passed?

**My approach**

School has $2000$ students,$2$/$5$ of students are in HS.$7$/$25$ of students are girls.This means,$18$/$25$ of students are boys.

And,$7$/$50$ of girls are passed.(because $1$/$2$(50%)  . $7$/$25$ )

How many  boys passed(=Let's say x).

Overall percentage=$40$%.

$7$/$50$ + x=$40$%.

I am not getting any link between the relations I have formed.

> Can anyone guide me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't work with fractions and relative numbers. Work with absolute numbers, that makes things easier.

40% of students are in HS, thus 800 students.

Of those, 28% are girls, thus 224 girls. And half of them passed on the test, thus 112.

On the other hand, of those 800 students, 40% passed, thus 320.

Of those 320-112=208 are boys.